# Switching comments box 'href' attribute from relative to absolute URL

Tags: facebook, comments, href

In the course of modifying the comments box integration for a client, to use the absolute URL, I discovered that the comments made while using the relative URL will not be shown. See http://cdpn.io/JethC for an example. How can we prevent losing older comments?

Comment: Did your relative URL before resolve to _exactly_ the same URL as the absolute one you are giving now? (That it's not working as you expect on your example page is quite obvious, because that relative URL there gets resolved using the prefix `http://codepen.io`, so those two URLs there are definitively different.)

Comment: Yes, the relative URL resolves to exactly the same as the absolute URL. I have created a test page on the original domain: http://www.avogel.co.uk/_dev/facebook-comments.html

Comment: Might be worth filing a bug report with FB then.